# Dropbox drop ins redraw/reinitialize Save to Dropbox button

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using javascript client side routing/ajax. So when the page loads and Dropbox's drop-in api scans the page for buttons like this:

```
<a href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/deroi5nwm6u7gdf/advice.png" class="dropbox-saver"></a>
```

The DOM for the `a` has not yet been drawn.

Is there a way to get the Drop-in API to rescan the page after the page has loaded correctly so that the button can appear?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to cause the library to re-scan the page, but you can always create the Saver button yourself, e.g. `Dropbox.createSaveButton(url, filename);`. (See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver#creating-buttons for details.)